# Artifactory fails after recovering admin password

Tags: artifactory

So I followed the following directions to recover the admin user id and password for Artifactory 2.6.1.

http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Users#ManagingUsers-RecreatingtheDefaultAdminUser

Artifactory is installed on my Linux server as a service. I use "service artifactory stop" and "service artifactory start" after copying and updating the password identified for version 2.x. I then copy the file to the `<artifactory_home>/etc/security.import.xml`

When I go to the UI after starting the service I get the follwing error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/artifactory] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.bind(ArtifactoryFilter.java:76)
at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:58)
```

If I remove the "security.import.xml" file from `/etc` and restart the service, everything is as it was before I started the process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the file is copied into [artifactory_home]/etc - it didn't show that in the original post.

Comment: Please note that you are looking on Artifactory 3 documentation, while using Artifactory 2. [That's the correct document](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF2X/Recreating+the+Default+Admin+Account)

Comment: Thanks Baruch. But the process is no different for a 2.6.1 installation between the two documents. And, as I stated, it doesn't work for me in either case.